# Create URL using values from options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a URL using values from the drop menu options.

The page I am working on is https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/pqLgc2dq/13/ and the idea would be the creator selects different components and then the URL given to a friend. This would open the exact build of what the creator has so the other user can evaluate (using angluarJS in this, so dont know if thatmakes a difference)

Admittedly, I do not have a clue on how to do this and wondered if anyone could help. if I haven't explained properly, please forgive me. I know it can be done as I have seen other sites do it, but I cant fathom it out. The idea would be the url populates the drop menu. or alternative would be a textbox which the user can see the extended info and then just share that using get code or load code button.(something like this http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/baseplanner/ but this is using fabricjs)

This is a basic select options page that I have created

https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/u5L1ewxx/3/

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <select>
      <option value = 1>1</option>
      <option value = 2>2</option>
      <option value = 3>3</option>
      <option value = 3>4</option>
      <option value = 3>5</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select>
      <option value = 1>1</option>
      <option value = 2>2</option>
      <option value = 3>3</option>
      <option value = 3>4</option>
      <option value = 3>5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select>
      <option value = 1>1</option>
      <option value = 2>2</option>
      <option value = 3>3</option>
      <option value = 3>4</option>
      <option value = 3>5</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="btnclick">Click me for sharable URL</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You'll have to put in a little more effort yourself. SO is not a free coding service. As far as I can see you have not tried anything on your own regarding creating the URL and parsing URL parameters on page load.

Comment: you are correct. i know i have to try, and i have been researching it...and will continue to whilst seeing if people can point me and what words to google to get my results

Comment: Please add an example of the URL you are aiming for (eg. what would it look like if drop down 1 was set to 1, drop down 2 was set to 2 and drop down 3 was set to 3?

Comment: i am thinking of a letter, ie if drop 1 = 1,drop 2 = 2,drop 3= 3 then URL will be www.example.com/aaabac   ie if its 1 add AA, if its 2 add AB, if its 3 add AC etc....

Answer (score 0):

In fact is nearly simple: Each select you have is a parameter. You could wrap them with a form and then create a "GET request"-like URL (ex: http://www.test.com?select1=value1&select2=value2&...&selectn=valuen)

Then on a call of this request load your page and inject the good value (with, javascript or whatever you want)

**EDIT:**

To build the get URL you'll just have to check `$form.serialize()`.

For the injection, you can inspire you from this https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/

An example on the loading of your page is (using the fonction of the precedente example):

```
$("select").each(function () {
    var $select = $(this);
    $select.val($.urlParam($select.attr("name"));
});
```

This code was not tested but I think there are no such modifications to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnclick").click(
    function() {
      var dropDown1 = document.getElementById("select-1").value;
      var dropDown2 = document.getElementById("select-2").value;
      var dropDown3 = document.getElementById("select-3").value;
      
      var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
      
      var url = 'https://example.com/a' + alphabet[dropDown1 - 1] + 'a' + alphabet[dropDown2 - 1] + 'a' + alphabet[dropDown3 - 1]; //Create your URL here using the dropDown1, dropDown2 and dropDown3 variables - this is just an example
      
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = url;
    }
  ); //end of onclick

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td><select id="select-1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select></td>
  <td><select id="select-2">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select></td>
  <td><select id="select-3">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select></td>
  <td><button id="btnclick">Click me for sharable URL</button></td>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Will this populate the values in the selects for the person who evaluates ?

Comment: Yes, when you get the value in JavaScript it gets it automatically, unless specific attributes are given on the elements